# django drf about many-to-many RelatedField custom field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I use the latest version of The Django REST Framework，
and The table in model is many-to-many related

My current model code looks like this:

model.py

```
class LvsDeploy(models.Model):
    MASTER = 'MASTER'
    BACKUP = 'BACKUP'
    ROLE_CHOICES = (
       (MASTER, 'MASTER'),
       (BACKUP, 'BACKUP')
    )
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    cluster_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    dip = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='DR IP')
    role = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=ROLE_CHOICES, verbose_name="role")



class LoadBalance(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    lb_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, verbose_name='load balance')
    cluster = models.ManyToManyField('LvsDeploy',related_name='cluster')
    vip = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='VIP')
    port = models.IntegerField(verbose_name='port')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.lb_name
```

My serializer code looks like this:

serializers.py

```
class LvsDeployReadOnly(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = LvsDeploy
        fields = '__all__'

class LoadBalanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    cluster_name = serializers.RelatedField(source='cluster.name',read_only=True)
    cluster = LvsDeployReadOnly(many=True)
    ##rs = RSInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = LoadBalance
        fields = '__all__'
        ##extra_fields = ['rs','cluster','cluster_name']
        extra_fields = ['rs','cluster','cluster_name']
```

My views code:

```
class BalanceList(views.APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        queryset = LoadBalance.objects.all()
        serializer = LoadBalanceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        print(serializer.data)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

and request actual output:

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cluster_name": null,
        "cluster": [
            {
               "id": 1,
               "cluster_name": "lvs_sz01",
               "dip": "1.1.1.6",
               "role": "BACKUP",

            },
            {
               "id": 2,
                "cluster_name": "lvs_sz01",
                "dip": "1.1.1.5",
                "role": "BACKUP",

            }
    ],
        "lb_name": "lb001",
        "vip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 80,
    }
]
```

But the cluster_name filed value is same in the dictionary of lists .
I want the output to look like this：

```
[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "cluster_name": "lvs_sz01",
        "cluster": [
            {
               "dip": "1.1.1.6",
               "role": "BACKUP",

            },
            {
                "dip": "1.1.1.5",
                "role": "BACKUP",

            }
        ],
        "lb_name": "lb001",
        "vip": "1.1.1.1",
        "port": 80,
    }
]
```

How should I change it? Can you help me ?

Comment: Your current output is pretty much the same as your desired output, is it just the `cluster_name` field that you are having issues with? The related objects could have more than one name, how would you get a single value in this case?

Comment: But you have many `cluster` for each `LoadBalance` so each `cluster_name` is different

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself with the following method：

```
class LoadBalanceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    cluster_name = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    cluster = LvsDeployReadOnly(many=True, read_only=True)
    rs = RSInfoSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = LoadBalance
        fields = '__all__'
        extra_fields = ['rs','cluster','cluster_name']

    def get_cluster_name(self,obj):
        print(type(obj.lb_name))
        lvs_cluster = obj.cluster.all()
        cluster_name  = [ i.cluster_name for i in lvs_cluster ][0]
        print(cluster_name)
        return cluster_name
```

Thanks!